# Using NDK and opengl

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es, android-ndk

I want to use NDK to implement Opengl in c++ but I have no idea how to use the ndk or set it up. Can someone give me a easy step by step instruction?

Comment: [No. Because that's against the rules.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I would recommend that you start with a Google sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/gles3jni

Comment: Or use Qt for Android, Unity and many others. Or figure out how to implement it from Android Studio and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html?hl=en

you should know a concept and basic steps about it.